# Compare traceroute IP with array values

Tags: arrays, bash, grep, traceroute

I am trying to compare if traceroute got successful or not in a bash. This is what I execute.

```
traceroute -m 30 -n 8.8.8.8 | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'
```

Output I receive:

> 8.8.8.8
>
> 8.8.8.8
>
> 192.192.192.21
>
> 192.191.191.32
>
> 192.18.128.48
>
> 8.8.8.8
>
> 192.168.168.168

I want to compare 8.8.8.8 (first value of the array) with last 3 values of the array, but when I try it, I get the error for float comparison.

Edit:

I tried this code, but it gives me error for float comparison.

```
for i in ${my_array[@]};
do
        if [ "${my_array[0]}" == "${my_array[i+1]}" ]; then
                echo "values are same";
        else
                echo "values are not same";
        fi
        echo $i;    
done
```

I know it is possible to use "bc" to solve float comparison problem, but is there any other way to solve this inline rather than storing it in an array ?

Comment: How are you comparing it? What is your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava , My expectation is that - if a first or second value (8.8.8.8) matches with remaining values , then i should get "1". I want to verify if route is reachable or not with "traceroute".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk` for your requirement:

```
traceroute -m 30 -n 8.8.8.8 |&
awk '$1=="traceroute"{ip=$3} /ms$/{a[++n] = ($1+0 == $1 ? $2 : $1)}
     END{for (i=n-2; i<=n; i++) if (ip == a[i]) exit 1}'
```

It will exit with status `1` when any IP address in last 3 lines match with IP in first line that starts with `traceroute`. If there is no match then exit status will be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to compare 8.8.8.8 (first value of the array) with last 3 values of the array

Just get the first value in the output and grep it with the last 3 lines:

```
output="8.8.8.8

8.8.8.8

192.192.192.21

192.191.191.32

192.18.128.48

8.8.8.8

192.168.168.168"

output=$(sed '/^$/d' <<<"$output") # remove empty lines

if grep -q "$(head -n1 <<<"$output")" <(tail -n3 <<<"$output"); then
        echo "Last three lines of output contain first line of the output"
else
        echo "fus ro dah"
fi
```

Now to your code:

```
for i in ${my_array[@]};
```

Iterates over **values** in `my_array`. If you want **indexes** of an array you need to iterate over them with `for ((i = 0; i < ${#my_array[@]}; ++i))`. Now I guess this:

```
for ((i = ${#my_array[@]} - 3; i < ${#my_array[@]}; ++i)); do
        if [ "${my_array[0]}" = "${my_array[i]}" ]; then
                echo "values are same";
        else
                echo "values are not same";
        fi
        echo $i;    
done
```

will probably do what you want, but using grep:

```
if grep -q "${my_array[0]}" <(printf "%s\n" "${my_array[@]: -3}"); then
    echo "values are same"
else
    echo "values are not same"
fi
```

is still simpler (for me).
Also note that the string comparison "operator" (dunno how it's called) in [test](https://man.cx/test) is `=` not `==`.